# Reference to Pop-up window in Windows Powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am working on testing-automation for a website I'm working on. I am using windows powershell to create scripts to do this. My problem is I need to click a link that opens up another window, I need a reference to that window some how.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://localhost:4611")
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
$link = $doc.getElementByID('link')
```

That is where I get a reference to the browser and the link. Then I click the link:

```
$link.click()
```

Which opens up a new window with things I need to test on it. How would I get a reference to this new window? It is not technically a child window of the first one.

I have tried to set the click of the link to a reference like this but it doesn't work:

```
$test = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$test = $link.click()
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the JavaScript function openwindow that gets called to open the window

```
function openwindow(url, name) {
   if (typeof openwindow.winrefs == 'undefined') {
      openwindow.winrefs = {};
   }
   if (typeof openwindow.winrefs[name] == 'undefined' || openwindow.winrefs[name].closed) {
    openwindow.winrefs[name] = window.open(url, name, 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=515,width=700,resizable=no,toolbar=no,status=no');
   } else {
      openwindow.winrefs[name].focus();
   };
};
```

The function gets called in a line of code that looks like this

```
column.For(i => "<a href='" + link + i.id + "?status=new' target='pat" + i.id + "'id'enc' onclick='openwindow(this.href,this.target);return false'>
```

**FINAL UPDATE:**
I ended up doing this slightly differently. I created a new Internet Explorer object and grabbed the href from the link and set all of the options and navigated to the window using powershell like the javascript does.

```
$ie2 = new-object -com "InternetExplorer"
$ie2.visible = $true
$ie2.menubar = $false
$ie2.height = 515
$ie2.width = 700
$ie2.resizable = $false
$link = $doc.getelementbyid('link')
$url = $link.href
$ie2.navigate($url)
```

I'd like to thank @scunliffe so much for helping me through this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a typo in this method: $doc.getElementByID('link')

it should be:

```
$doc.getElementById('link')
                  ^ lowercase d
```

**Update:**

Based on the follow up code/comments... you should be able to extract a reference to the window with something like this:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://localhost:4611")
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
$link = $doc.getElementById('link')
$link.click()
```

The link has a target attribute set that the openwindow function uses to assign a name to the popup window.

The openwindow function itself, stores a reference to the popup in a property called winrefs, thus this should now get the window... (if my expectations of the PowerShell syntax within the IE window are correct.

```
$targetName = $link.target
$popupHandle = $ie.openwindow.winrefs[$targetName]
```

Comment: windows powershell is case insensitive

Comment: ah, my apologies... I'm just used to seeing this trip up users all over the web. So why does this link open a new window? does it have a target attribute set? or does it call JavaScript?

Comment: ah, ok, in that case, trace the JavaScript... if it does.... `foo = window.open(...);` then you should be able to reference it as `$ie.foo` if it submits a form or "clicks" another link with a `target`, you should be able to do `$ie.targetName` (if I understand correctly how PowerShell taps into IE).

Comment: I did not write the javascript function. `openwindow.winrefs[name] = window.open(url, name, 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=515,width=700,resizable=no,toolbar=no,status=no');` is what it does

Comment: ah, so you might be able to gain access through: `$ie.openwindow.winrefs["name"]` where "name" should be replaced with whatever was originally passed in to that code for the `name` variable.

Comment: yeah I've tried that but it says I can't reference a null array. I wonder if maybe it just doesn't hold a reference to the new window.

Comment: Hmm - if it opens with `something = window.open(...);` then the something (left hand side) does contain a reference to the popup.  I think the catch is trying to figure out the exact syntax required.  If you can provide the opener page source we can help.

Comment: I added some code to the question. I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: $targetName = $link.target works and gets the correct target name. But the second line gives me the error

Comment: "Cannot index into a null array"

Comment: hmm, not sure... is there a chance you can provide a URL to this page?  If it is private and you'd rather not share it out (too much) I'd be more than happy to assist if you'd like.. ping/DM me on twitter @scunliffe