# An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am trying to create a reference to an IE popup window. My script clicks a link which opens a page in a new window. To get access to this new window, I am doing the following:

```
$allreg = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$popup = $allreg.Windows() | ? {$_.LocationName -like 'Wells'}
$popup.document
```

Error:
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Access is denied. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

**UPDATE:** 
So I was able to get a reference to the window link, but still not able to get the document object of the window. Any ideas?

Comment: One of the returned Windows your accessing are probably running as another user. Try running the script as admin.

Comment: Hmm, but I am already running my PowerShell ISE as Administrator.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are running it as admin (right click powershell and run as admin)? Having an administrator user isn't enough with UAC.

Comment: Correct. Each time I start up PowerShell I right click and run as admin.

Comment: "My script clicks a link" Are you using the IE com object to click the link? Then trying to get the data from the pop up? If so this is very tricky. Only solution that has worked is to get the URL of the link and navigate to it directly in the com object. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434586/reference-to-pop-up-window-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: I tried both with COM object and just passing the URL like $ie.navigate($link.href) but neither work. Still unable to get a reference to the popup window document @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Rather than create a Shell.Application object and find the correct window, I just created a 2nd IE.application object and navigated directly like so,

```
$ie2 = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

$ie2.Navigate("https://wffnet.wellsfargo.com/ilonline/feature/wff/seller/guide.start.go")
```

This was I was able to grab the document object of $ie2